# How to test a hypothesis about the mean based on an assumed normal distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, normal-distribution, t-distribution

> The entrance onto a major bridge in New York City was engineered to accommodate
>   an average of $3800$ vehicles per hour. However, a random sample of nine observations
>   gives an average of $4045.9$ vehicles per hour with a standard deviation of $201.3$
>   vehicles. Use a $5\%$ significance level to test the claim that the true average number
>   of vehicles per hour is more than $3800$. Assume that the number of vehicles per
>   hour is normally distributed.

I'm not sure on how to start. Can you please help?

Comment: Tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: I've identified that my null hypothesis is x=3800 and that my alternative hypothesis is x>3800. I'm just unsure if I should use a t-distribution or a standard normal distribution.

Comment: How does one decide whether to use the normal or the t distribution? What are the criteria for selecting between them?

Comment: Is it when you have to evaluate a test? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Try reading the introductory paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test). Why would you use the t-distribution instead of the normal?

Comment: Ah is it because we know the test hypothesis?

Comment: What does it say in the 1st paragraph at the link?

Comment: It says "When the scaling term is unknown and is replaced by an estimate based on the data, the test statistic (under certain conditions) follows a Student's t distribution."

Comment: Right. Now, what is the "scaling term" for your situation, & was it known beforehand or was it estimated from your data?

Comment: It was estimated

Comment: So should you use the t-distribution or the normal distribution?

Comment: soo a t distribution

Comment: Alright but how can I find my population sample?

Comment: Right. Now what do you do next?

Comment: What do you mean by "population sample"? That doesn't sound like anything I'm familiar with / relevant.

Comment: I use the equation t= (average - estimated average)/((standard deviation/sqrt(population size))

Comment: well the "n" in the equation

Comment: I think that isn't the correct formula. Look at the formula for a 1 sample t-test at the link. You don't use "average", but something else. Also your population size is assumed to be infinite. What does the '"n" in the equation' refer to?

Comment: how is that possible if it's infinite? It'll be a fraction over infinite...

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/2/5/3/253733e602b3c7d76cca80075d6a2998.png I'm using this equation

Comment: The population is assumed to be infinite. Therefore, n is not the population size. What is it? There is a hint right after the formula at the link. Also, what is in the numerator?

Comment: Ohhh is it the 9 observers? If it is that, s would be 201.3 and the μ is 4045.9.

Comment: Right, $n=9$, but $\mu_0$ is not $4045.9$. What is it? What are the symbols in the numerator for?

Comment: @gung if you can gather those hints into an answer (pretty much a copy/paste with some connecting phrases perhaps) I think that would be pretty reasonable as a answer for a self-study Q.

Answer (score 2):

Your first question is to determine whether you are using the normal distribution or the $t$-distribution.  These are possible sampling distributions for your test statistic.  If you are estimating the standard deviation from your data, there is some uncertainty about the true value of the SD.  You need to take that additional uncertainty into account.  The $t$-distribution, with its higher variance / fatter tails, does this for you.  You should use the $t$-distribution here.

Next we need to determine the value for $n$.  It is not the size of your population.  Your population is assumed to be infinite.  Instead, it is the size of your sample.  From the problem description, I gather your $n=9$.
$$
t = \frac{\bar x-\mu_0}{\frac{s}{\sqrt n}}
$$
Lastly, the numerator for the one-sample $t$-test (in the formula above) lists two values.  You need to figure out what those refer to and plug in the appropriate numbers from your problem description.  Then (with a little arithmetic), you will be done.